# 2006 Corvette battery tender location

Tags: battery, battery-charger, corvette

I have a 2006 Corvette (C6) that isn’t driven a whole lot and I want to hook up a better tender the most convenient way possible. Obviously I can hook it up directly to the battery terminals but I’ve seen some things online where you can plug it into the cigarette lighter power outlet on the interior and I was wondering if this is possible or safe to do. Thank you

Comment: I believe you can attach a trickle charger pretty much anywhere you have a continuous positive and then a ground attachment point. I wouldn't use a trickle charger though, I'd get a battery tender. A trickle charger will continue to charge, where as a tender will maintain the battery (stop charging when it's full and check it regularly to ensure it's full).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes battery tender that’s what I meant. And thank you

Comment: @jt.j ive seen some where its a kit and there is a wiring harness to give you a plug in an easier location to plug into.  Its gonna look like the block heater plug for a diesel